# Animation - Stop Animation and Display specific image from the animation

Tags: android, xml, animation

How can i stop an animation (i think with .stop() ). Then it should be a picture of the animation appear static. The second picture should be the one shown.

How do I do that?

Heres the XML animation-list:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/app" android:duration="1200"/>
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/app2" android:duration="250"/>
 </animation-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by myself, after a few hours research.

```
Object tag = layout.getTag();
    int backgroundId = R.drawable.night;

    if( tag != null && ((Integer)tag).intValue() == backgroundId) {
        backgroundId = R.drawable.day;
        playAnimation();
    }
    else
    {
        animatedLoerg.selectDrawable(1);
        animatedLoerg.stop();
    }

    layout.setTag(backgroundId);
    layout.setBackgroundResource(backgroundId);
```

Solved it with the tag.